# Display RGBA32-BMP Images on Linux

Tags: c, linux, jpeg, rgba

today I got some code to review.
Since the code is going to work on an headless pc the code saves every frame as a seperate RGBa image.
On my Ubuntu install I cannot view theses images, GIMP complains about a broken header. Imagemagick options convert or display also did not show any images.

Here's the code fragment that generates the image:

```
if (act.doScreenshot || (act.doVideo && buddhabrot_animate.animating))
{
    uchar4* tmpBuffer = new uchar4[env.static_env.save.imageW
                                   * env.static_env.save.imageH];
    for (int i = 0; i < env.static_env.save.imageW * env.static_env.save.imageH; i++)
    {
        const unsigned char tmp = tmpBuffer[i].x;
        tmpBuffer[i].x = tmpBuffer[i].z;
        tmpBuffer[i].z = tmp;
    }

    char filename[128];

    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "w+b");

    BITMAPFILEHEADER bmpFH;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpIH;
    memset(&bmpFH, 0, sizeof(bmpFH));
    memset(&bmpIH, 0, sizeof(bmpIH));

    bmpFH.bfType = 19778; //"BM"
    bmpFH.bfSize = sizeof(bmpFH) + sizeof(bmpIH) + env.static_env.save.imageW * env.static_env.save.imageH;
    bmpFH.bfOffBits = sizeof(bmpFH) + sizeof(bmpIH);
    bmpIH.biSize = sizeof(bmpIH);
    bmpIH.biWidth = env.static_env.save.imageW;
    bmpIH.biHeight = env.static_env.save.imageH;
    bmpIH.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpIH.biBitCount = 32;

    fwrite(&bmpFH, 1, sizeof(bmpFH), fp);
    fwrite(&bmpIH, 1, sizeof(bmpIH), fp);
    fwrite
        (tmpBuffer,
         env.static_env.save.imageW * env.static_env.save.imageH,
         sizeof(uchar4),
         fp);
    fclose(fp);
    delete[] tmpBuffer;
```

Is there any way to look at the image?
Or maybe another way to save the images as JPGs?

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate `bmpFH.bfSize` correctly, you need to multiply the number of pixels in the image by the size of the pixels (4). For example:

```
bmpFH.bfSize = sizeof(bmpFH) + sizeof(bmpIH) + env.static_env.save.imageW * env.static_env.save.imageH * sizeof(uchar4);
```

You should also initialize `bmpIH.biCompression` to `BI_RGB`. It'll work anyway because its value happens to be zero, but it's good to be explicit. You also might want to negate the value you're assigning to `bmpIH.biHeight` as positive height values indicate a bottom up image.